# Access <li> elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to use a input box from SELECT2(jQuery Plugin) and want to send it with PHP Post to the server.
How do i access these Elements (A, Adolf, B)?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything from your side?

Comment: you need to work within the plugin API . See docs. What exactly are you wanting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Select2` (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) it overrides `<select>` element.
So probably you use like this:

```
<select id="my-select"><option>...</option></select>
```

And in JS:

```
$("#my-select").select2();
```

This way - if you want to read current value just use:

```
$("#my-select").val();
```

or using Select2 API:

```
$("#my-select").select2("val");
```

If you need to get **all values** from `<option>`'s - you can do it like this:

```
$("#my-select option").map(function() {return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.select2-search-choice div');
```

if you want to get the text of the elements, then use `$('.select2-search-choice div').text();`

Comment: Please update `select2-search-choice div` to `.select2-search-choice div`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through `$('li.seleact2-search-choice').children('div');` or simply `$('.select2-search-choice div');`

Answer (score 0):

To get an Array of the values use the API from select2:

```
var data = $("#YourSelect2Element").select2("val");
```

You have to change the selector in the selector you used to create the select2 input.
[See the docs.](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation)